# Swift XCTest namespace bug?

Tags: swift, namespaces, xctest

I'm wondering if I've found a namespace / XCTest bug in Swift 1.2/XCode 6.4(6E23):

I have a .swift file with a public function `encode` that takes a few parameters. I also have an XCTest file to test the `encode` function.

My XCTest file imports my code fine – I'm able to call public functions from it and even the function that is causing me trouble, `encode`, is autocompleting just fine when I start writing it out. However, when I try to compile it, I can see that it fails (with "Extra argument in call") because the compiler thinks I'm calling Foundation.encode rather than my own.

Changing the name of it makes it work fine, but that is beside the point which is this; Swift is supposed to prioritise your module over the system's so is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be the issue is this:

Does the swift file in which `encode` is declared have `Target Membership` set to both you're test bundle and your main bundle? If not, select the swift file and in the right menu, under `Target Membership`, select your test bundle as well (it should be a checkmark).

Comment: It does and, alas, it makes no difference. I have a dummy project that demonstrates the problem [here](http://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmPQanXdcNjYEbsVPvBR53qPB6sxg34zqErPnXoxKYPiX9)

Comment: I've filed a radar on this [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4989937497669632)